# AJAX: Have JSON data from two separate AJAX calls dump into a single unordered list

Tags: jquery, json, ajax, html-lists

I am building a hierarchical menu that relies on AJAX calls to pull data from two separate JSON files. I am currently relying on the following 2 calls to create a **Categories** unordered list and a **Sections** unordered list:

```
//AJAX call to the the Categories JSON file
var $requestcategories = $.ajax({
  url: 'https://myURL/categories.json',
  dataType: 'json',
  type: 'get',
  cache: 'false',
  success: function(data) {
    let $ul = $('<ul id="categories"/>'); 
    let html = data.categories.map(c => `<ul class='category'><li class='cat' catid=${c.id}><a>${c.name}</a></li></ul>`);
    $ul.append(html).appendTo('#navbar');
  }
  });//This closes the Categories AJAX call


//AJAX call to the the Sections JSON file
var $requestsections = $.ajax({
  url: 'https://myURL/sections.json',
  dataType: 'json',
  type: 'get',
  cache: 'false',
  success: function(data) {
    let $ul = $('<ul id="sections"/>'); 
    let html = data.sections.map(s => `<ul class='section'><li class="sec" secid=${s.id} categoryid=${s.category_id} parentsecid=${s.parent_section_id}><a href="${s.html_url}">${s.name}</a></li></ul>`);
    $ul.append(html).appendTo('#navbar');
    }
  });//This closes the Sections AJAX call
```

Once the lists are in my HTML output, I rely on jQuery to move the Section list items around so that each one sits under the correct Category list item.

Is there an efficient way to consolidate my AJAX calls so that -- rather than having the Category data and Section data initially dump to two separate lists, I can have all the data load to a single unordered list (maybe called 'MenuItems')? My sense is that it would be easier and less resource-intensive to work with and reorder the menu items if they were initially dumped to the same parent UL.

(On a related note: Is there a way to consolidate the two AJAX calls so that I can grab all the data from both JSON files as part of a SINGLE call?)

Thanks in advance for tips and feedback on this.

Comment: You can always combine the things the ajax is calling - assuming you have access to them - or else you could write another server-side file that gathers the results of both of those called files into one, then returns it. This is in answer to the question of combining. -- as for being performant, seems to me the best thing to do is keep the two data values and don't do any work with them (no map, no append, etc) till you've got them both. Then handle them together. Thus - your success functions would store their data, not manipulate it, till both are ready.

Comment: Not sure if I understand what you are trying to do or how your data is structured, but I think you could use [`Promise.all()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Promise/all) to call a single function when **both** ajax call resolve and have your responses on a single object.